# Nginx return status code from regex grouping

Tags: nginx, regex

How can I have nginx return a status code from a regular express match?

`location ~* "^/([\d]{3})" {
    return $1;
}`

Returns an error 'invalid return code "$1"'

I'm trying to setup a test environment where I can go to /401 and be returned a 401 code, /402 and get a 402 etc, and not have to just add each location separately.

Comment: i've just try to do it that using 'return' with variables but no luck. But, you can use something like that;
```
 if ($1 = "403") {
  return 404;
 }

```